# Activity Indicator for Swift only covering part of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to do the activity indicator with a background that covers the entire screen.  My problem is that when I run the app, it only covers a portion of the screen.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: self.view.frame)
            self.activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
            self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            print("save the data on to core data and onto Parse, then segue to the new input controller")

            let file = PFFile(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!)
            let insurance = PFObject(className: "Insurance")

            insurance["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
            insurance["imageFile"] = file as PFFile
            insurance.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error ) -> Void in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                if (success) {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToDetails", sender: self)
                }else{
                    self.displayAlert("Problems Savings", message: "There was an error with saving the data")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

[image: Display with the code above]

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Apply the constraints to it as centerx and centery to the superview

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

to

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```

Judging from your screenshot, the frame of `self.view` is something like `(0, 64, /* some width */, /* some height */)`. The `y` origin is 64 points down the screen. You copy this frame and give the activity indicator that same frame. This would would if you were adding the activity indicator to a view whose `y` origin is at 0 points. Since the view you add it to is already 64 points down the screen, adding the activity indicator with that frame will make the activity indicators real y in terms of the phone screen 128 points down the screen. I got this number from adding the `y` origin of the view and the `y` origin of the activity indicator.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve this problem is pushing the loading indicator on topmost controller:

```
private var topMostController: UIViewController? {
    var presentedVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let pVC = presentedVC?.presentedViewController {
        presentedVC = pVC
    }

    return presentedVC
}
```

You might want to try this, a project of mine: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZLoadingActivity